# How to create a ruby enum and parse the value from querystring?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to create an enumeration that I will need to initialize from a value from the querystring.

Example of what I have and what I need to do:

```
class UserType
   NONE = 0
   MEMBER = 1
   ADMIN = 2
   SUPER = 3
end
```

Now in my querystring I will have:

```
/users/load_by_type?type=2
```

Now in my controller I will get the value 2 from the querystring, I then need to have a UserType object which has the value 'MEMBER'.

How can I do this?

If my class isn't really a good enumeration hack, please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'd rather use hashes for this kind of thing, but just for fun:

```
class Foo
  BAR = 1
  STAN = 2

  class << self
    def [](digit)
      constants.find { |const| const_get(const) == digit }
    end
  end
end

puts Foo[1] # BAR
puts Foo[2] # STAN
```

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this.

```
require 'active_record'


# set up db
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection adapter: 'sqlite3', database: ':memory:'


# define schema
ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  suppress_messages do
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :role
    end
  end
end


# define class
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  Roles = %w[none member admin super].map(&:freeze)
  validates_inclusion_of :role, in: Roles
end


# specification
describe User do
  before { User.delete_all }

  let(:valid_role)    { User::Roles.first }
  let(:invalid_role)  { valid_role.reverse }
  it 'is valid if its role is in the Roles list' do
    User.new.should_not be_valid
    User.new(role: valid_role).should be_valid
    User.new(role: invalid_role).should_not be_valid
  end

  let(:role)          { User::Roles.first }
  let(:other_role)    { User::Roles.last }
  it 'can find users by role' do
    user_with_role       = User.create! role: role
    user_with_other_role = User.create! role: other_role
    User.find_all_by_role(role).should == [user_with_role]
  end
end
```

It does have the disadvantage of using an entire string (255 chars) for the enumeration method, but it also has the advantage of readability and ease of use (it would probably come in as "/users/load_by_role?role=admin"). Besides, if at some point it winds up costing too much, it should be easy to update to use a small integer.